# Default browser mode IE

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

How do I change the default browser mode for IE from one of the browser modes accessible from f12 developer tools!? IE 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same issue when testing applications on my local server.

I did the following:

1.Open IE
2.Alt-T
3.Click 'Tools'
4.Click 'Compatibility View Settings'

Here I was able to manipulate the settings that controlled my browser mode. By unchecking the 
'display intranet sites in compatibility view' my problem was resolved.

I have not been able to persist this setting beyond the browsing session, but it is active for the life of the current session.

Comment: Are you able to specify the exact IE mode you want to be used as the default?